# Failed to find rosdep

Tags: rosdep

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I have copied the gsl package into my ros workspace, it appears in rospack list, but I'm getting this warnings:

```
Failed to find rosdep gsl for package my_package on OS:ubuntu version:lucid
WARNING: Rosdeps [u'gsl'] could not be resolved

[ rosmake ] WARNING: Rosdep did not detect the following system dependencies as installed: gsl Consider using --rosdep-install option or `rosdep install my_package`
```

However it compiles and works ok, but there is probably something wrong? Can you halp to get rid of this warnings?

Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/34016/failed-to-find-rosdep-.../) by [liborw](https://answers.ros.org/users/2302/liborw/) on ROS Answers with karma: 801 on 2012-05-14

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

In `my_package`'s manifest.xml change

```
<rosdep name="gsl" />
```

to

```
<depend package="gsl" />
```

---

Originally posted by [Cody](https://answers.ros.org/users/1588/cody/) with karma: 125 on 2012-05-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [liborw](https://answers.ros.org/users/2302/liborw/) on 2012-05-14**:
Thanks, but actually in my_package the depend was correct but in the gsl package there was  so I have change it to  and it works.

**Comment by [Cody](https://answers.ros.org/users/1588/cody/) on 2012-05-15**:
Ah. Glad to hear it wasn't too tricky. There seem to be some strange issues with rosdep these days.